# Env variable is not available within Nuxt app

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

Following the docs ([here](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/) and [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config/)) I've set up my `.env` variable `IFRAME_CHECKER` this way:

.env:

```
IFRAME_CHECKER=https://path.to.some.script
```

nuxt.config.js:

```js
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
  iframeChecker: process.env.IFRAME_CHECKER
}
```

Yet in my components (within the `mounted()` hook for example), `this.$config.iframeChecker` returns `null`. Why?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(process.env.BASE_URL)` to the top of your `nuxt.config.js`, so we can check if the values are even in `process.env`?

Comment: It's not possible to use `console.log()` there, at least it doesn't work in my case

Comment: It should work at the very top of the file, before the `export default {...}`. The output should be printed as soon as you run nuxt. My idea is to use the regular `dotenv` module as intended and add `require('dotenv').config()` to the top of the config file, so your variables get loaded into `process.env` and you can use them in the `publicRuntimeConfig`. Your error could be a result of the variables not actually being loaded into `process.env`, hence the value `null`.

Comment: Yes I've put it before `export default`, doesn't log anything

Comment: Alright, nevermind. Nuxt actually automatically populates `process.env`. I also wasn't able to reproduce your issue using your code. Would be awesome if you could provide a minimal example project that has this issue.

Comment: Are talking local or production environment here? Did you touched to any configuration related, like the `.gitignore` or alike? Also, where do you call your `iframeChecker` env variable (a layout, component)? Try this syntax too: `IFRAME_CHECKER="https://path.to.some.script"` (with double quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't replicate your issue.

***Note: You won't need the @nuxtjs/dotenv package.***

I got it working with the following:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    iframeChecker: process.env.IFRAME_CHECKER || 'https://nuxtjs.org'
  },
  ...
}
```

**.env**

```
IFRAME_CHECKER=http://test
```

The `iframeChecker` should be available like this:

**mycomponent.vue**

```
export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$config.iframeChecker)
  }
  ...
}
```

[image: console.log screenshot]

Comment: It does work now, I did nothing since I posted my question except restart my machine. This is not the first time it happens to me: getting stuck for hours on something, and on the following day it works. I'm suspecting Webpack has issues: even when killing the `npm run dev` or `npm run serve` process and restarting it, a problem (like the one discussed in this question) can persist, until the machine is restarted. It's incredibly annoying, does it sound a bell for anyone?

Comment: I am glad you figured it out @drake035

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall `@nuxt/dotenv`

.env

```js
IFRAME_CHECKER=https://path.to.some.script
```

in your nuxt.config.js:

```js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },
    iframeChecker: process.env.IFRAME_CHECKER
  }
}
```

can access like this

```js
this.$config.IFRAME_CHECKER
```

Comment: But https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/ starts with "It's time to migrate from @nuxtjs/dotenv module to use our new runtime config" so the point of using this config pattern is to not use `dotenv` right?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `@nuxt/dotenv` module anymore, that's right. Though it's likely that you still need to use the regular `dotenv` module in your config so your variables are loaded into `process.env`.

Comment: No need, `dotenv` is still backed into Nuxt. No point into this module right now tbh.